# How can I install libEGL.dylib on MacOS?

Tags: macos, opengl, homebrew, dylib, egl

I'm trying to use EGL via LWJGL on MacOS to use offscreen rendering.
It seems to throw an exception of the missing library `libEGL.dylib`.

I couldn't find this library on package distribution service like brew.
However, I could find several minor repositories on Github containing libEGL.dylib. I don't think this is safe to use.

How can I find the binary officially, or find the source to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any canonical libEGL implementation. The header files are part of the standard, but the implementation isn't.

[MoltenGL](https://moltengl.com/downloads/) has a binary download available (the second one, "OpenGL ES 2 for macOS").

If you prefer an open-source implementation, Google's [ANGLE](https://github.com/google/angle) also implements EGL and supposedly supports macOS. And for what it's worth, it appears that Apple is using this in WebKit for iOS as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Building ANGLE from source](https://github.com/google/angle/blob/main/doc/DevSetup.md) is... a little insane right now (8.4 gigs of source code, as of late 2023). So you can pilfer the EGL libraries out of, say, Chromium by saying

```
export SDL_VIDEO_EGL_DRIVER="/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/Frameworks/Chromium Framework.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries/libEGL.dylib"
```

... or alternatively, just copy `libEGL.dylib` and `libGLESv2.dylib` from any application that has them (like Chromium, or Electron etc.) into `/usr/local/lib`.